# How to call a function inside another function and make that run over and over

Tags: python, function, random

Firstly, they ask me to write a function that stimulates a rolling of ONE dice. The function generates the random number in `range(1,6)`. Take no parameters and returns the random number generated
Then, it asks me to write another function that takes a SIZE of the list to create parameter. The function generates FIVE(size) random numbers in `range(1,6)` and assign each number to a list element. Then the function must call the first function to stimulate the roll of a dice.

I have already tried to do the first function. But I am stuck at how to make the first function generate five numbers to assign to the list, and i dont understand the word "take a SIZE of the list". Does it mean `len(list)` ?

```
def roll_dice():
    dice = random.randint(1,6) #Import random
    return dice

dice = roll_dice()

def deal_hand(dice):
     for index in range(len(lst)) #List is a 5-element list
         lst[index] = dice
     return lst[dice]

     dice = roll_dice()  
     step = step + 1
```

I expect the output to be:

```
lst = [1,2,4,5,6]
```

when run again, it will have random numbers like `[2,4,5,1,3]`

Comment: This is asking you to create a function that accepts a number, then creates a list with that number of elements.

Answer (score 0):

You were quite close, this is one simple way to do this:

```
import random


def roll_die():
    return random.randint(1, 6)


def make_list(size):
    ls = []
    for _ in range(size):
        ls.append(roll_die())
    return ls


print(make_list(6))
```

> Output:
>
> ```
> [4, 6, 4, 3, 6, 2]
> ```